# I need to write my expectations from a job

Tags: grammar, writing-style, writing

I`m looking for a job as a developer, so I need to write my expectations for the job. Am I right grammatically writing this into my CV?

> I am looking for opportunities for professional growth and for taking responsibility for my job.

I`m afraid of putting 'for' four times.

Comment: Hi Serge. I'm afraid we don't do general proofreading. If you have a specific thing you think may be wrong in the sentence, please ask about that. Otherwise I'm afraid this question will be closed.

Comment: I`m afraid of putting 'for' four times. is it Ok?

Comment: Please edit the question to ask about that specifically. And say whether you are concerned about style or about some grammatical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am seeking opportunities for professional growth and job responsibility.

The four fors are grammatical, but might be confusing. This sentence says largely the same thing, but is a bit more concise.